# How can I open multiple pop-up windows using js?

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm currently working on an art project and I would like to know how to open multiple pop-up windows in order to make it look like one of those websites filled with visual pollution. The more chaotic it looks, the better. 
So far I've managed to make only one pop-up, using the following code:

```
function popup() { 
 window.open('test.html','Tab Heading','height=300,width=150, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
}
window.onload = popup;
```

I am not very experienced with js so I've been having some difficulties to find a way to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

You need different names for each (second parameter) or the window will be reused

NOTE: The code below will not work in SO's sandbox

```js
const options = "height=300,width=150,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no";
let cnt = 10; // for example

function popup() { 
 let w = window.open('test.html',"name"+cnt,options);
 if (!w) console.log("sorry, not allowed to pop");
 else { 
   cnt--;
   if (cnt>0) setTimeout(popup,1000); // pop the next
 }  
}
window.addEventListener("load",popup)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was trying to do but couldn't figure out how. Very helpful! :)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter specifies the instance name. If it's already open, next time, the tab will open on the same ***instance***. So, to navigate that you may append a unique value, say `Date.now` to allow opening multiple tabs.

```
function popup() { 
     window.open('test.html', 'Open_' + Date.now(),'height=300,width=150, toolbar=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no');
    }
    window.onload = popup;
```